# neo4j cannot find JAVA_HOME when checking service status

Tags: java, linux, neo4j

I installed `neo4j 1.8.2` on opensuse 12.2/64. To do so I had to add the `JAVA_HOME` path in the `/etc/profile` file as:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/64/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/:
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/java/64/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/bin/;
```

Now when I try to check the server status I get the following error

```
>service neo4j-service status

    neo4j-service.service - LSB: The Neo4J graph database server. See http://neo4j.org
              Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/neo4j-service)
              Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri, 26 Apr 2013 17:13:56 +0200; 10s ago
             Process: 7234 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/neo4j-service start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
              CGroup: name=systemd:/system/neo4j-service.service

    Apr 26 17:13:56 linux-wwcz neo4j-service[7234]: which: no java in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/...bin)
    Apr 26 17:13:56 linux-wwcz neo4j-service[7234]: Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
    Apr 26 17:13:56 linux-wwcz neo4j-service[7234]: We cannot execute
```

It's quite puzzling considering `neo4j-service` links to `./bin/neo4j`, namely the file used at installation time with

```
./bin/neo4j install
```

Some ideas on what is going on here?

Thanks

**SOLVED**

Actually I was using jdk 7 instead of **jdk 6**

**EDIT 2**

According to the official neo4j page one runs the server using `neo4j start`. But I got into troubles when trying to run `service neo4j start/status/stop` as suggested in the [Installing Neo4j in Linux](http://www.genericarticles.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Installing_Neo4j_in_Linux) how-to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing them to this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/64/jdk1.7.0_21/:
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/java/64/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Actually it does not solve the problem. I went through the installation process again but I keep getting the same error when I check the server status.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly for the question, but I reached here because I also though Neo4j could not find the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` when

```
sudo neo4j start
```

My problem was that OS reset environment variables when using `sudo`.

```
sudo -E neo4j start
```

solved my problem.